# How to typeset a "small" non-breaking space

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I can use `~` to produce a non-breaking space. But it is too large for me, and I would like a non-breaking space of the size of `\,` for example. Is it possible ?

Comment: The space inserted by `\,` *is* non breaking.

Comment: upss... :) sorry.

Comment: Don't worry, it's been a good occasion for describing some lesser known TeX features. For example, *why* `\,` is a non breaking space.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

There are two kinds of spacing that TeX can use: skips and kerns. The first sort of space can be flexible (the interword space is a skip, for instance), while the second one is rigid.

Both disappear at line breaks, but TeX will never break a line at a kern (unless it's followed by a skip), while it's willing to do it at skips. Therefore

```
word\,word
```

would *never* be broken across lines.

The command `\,` inserts a kern, precisely it's defined (in text mode) as

```
\kern 0.16667em
```

(where 1em is approximately the width of an uppercase "M", whence the name, or near the font size in points); so the space inserted by `\,` is 1/6 of an em.

Conversely, `~` is defined as a skip: its definition is `\nobreakspace`, which translates into

```
\leavevmode\nobreak\
```

(the last is "backslash+space"). There will be no line break at it, because the skip inserted by `\<space>` is preceded by so high a penalty that breaks are impossible (`\nobreak` translates into `\penalty 10000`).

You can space by inserting `\kern` yourself, but using a macro is preferable. If you need that the space is non breakable *and* flexible, use the same trick as `~`:

```
\nobreak\hspace{.16667em plus .08333em}
```

would insert a space normally equal to 1/6 of an em, but stretchable to 1/4 of an em.

I left out the `\leavevmode` because such spaces should always be inserted *between* words. LaTeX takes that precaution, because users might use `~` in order to indent lines (which is not the best thing to do, though).

Comment: *`\nobreak\hspace{.16667em plus .13333em}` would insert a space normally equal to 1/6 of an em, but stretchable to 1/5 of an em.* Are you sure that's right? Maybe I just am not familiar with the syntax, but it seems like that space would be stretchable to about 0.3em. If you want stretchable to approximately 1/5 em, shouldn't that be `.16667em plus .03333em` (which works out to .19997em)?

Comment: So is `\kern 0.16667em` the same as `\nobreak\hspace{.16667em}`?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Not really: `\unskip` wouldn't remove it (there's `\unkern`).

Comment: why is wrong with "inserting `\kern` yourself"?

Comment: @snoram It's not wrong, but a macro is *preferable*, so you don't have to chase across your document for `\kern` if you realize that you have to change to 1/4 of an em instead of 1/6.