# thin unbreakable space

Tags: babel

As you maybe know, in French typography, "big" punctuation marks (`!?;»`) must be preceded by a thin undividable space (obviously `«` must be followed by a thin unbreakable space, and as a matter of exception, `:` should be preceded by a normal unbreakable space), see for example in French http://fvsch.com/articles/espaces-ponctuation/.

Here an example :
[image]

The solution used by `babel` extension is to use in every case a normal unbreakable space with `~`.

I have three questions to solve this trouble :

1. What is the actual definition of `~`?
2. Is there a way to change this definition of `~`?
3. Is there a way to force `babel` to use thin unbreakable space with `!?;«»` and normal unbreakable space with `:`.

Thank you for any clue.

Comment: Did you look at [frenchle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/french/frenchle)?

Comment: You mean *thin* unbreakable space with `!?;«»` and *normal* space with `:`, I believe.

Comment: I just read the article you've provided a link to. It's disappointing that the author of the article seems to be quite unaware of what TeX/LaTeX and the `babel` package do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A counterexample to what you assert. With `babel` the *right* spaces are used, according to French typographic rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{«}{\og}
\newunicodechar{»}{\fg}

\begin{document}

Une phrase en français; sans intérêt, avec signes diacritiques:
nous pouvons voir qu'il est correct!

Les \og guillemets\fg{} sont corrects aussi.

Les «guillemets» sont corrects aussi.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the spaces are thin before `;` and `!` (the same for `?`), but they're normal spaces before the colon.

For guillemets, the standard way is to use `\og` and `\fg`, but one can redefine `«` and `»` for getting the same effect.

Some excerpts of the log file when `\showoutput` is used:

```
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 f
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 r
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 a
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 n
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 ?
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 a
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 i
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 s
....\penalty 10000
....\kern 1.6663
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 ;
[...]
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 d
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 i
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 a
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 c
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 r
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 i
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 i
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 q
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 u
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 s
....\penalty 10000
....\glue 3.33252 plus 1.66626 minus 1.11084
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 :
....\glue 3.33252 plus 1.66626 minus 1.11084
[...]
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 c
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 o
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 r
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 r
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 c
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\penalty 10000
....\kern 1.6663
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 !
```

A thin space is exactly `\kern 1.6663`, while the two spaces around the colon are normal interword spaces.

If you want to change the space before the colon to be a normal interword space without stretching (but with shrinking) and the space after/before open/close guillemets, just redefine `\FBcolonspace` and `\FBguillspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{«}{\og}
\newunicodechar{»}{\fg}

\renewcommand{\FBcolonspace}{\hspace{\fontdimen 2\font minus\fontdimen4\font}}
\renewcommand{\FBguillspace}{\thinspace}

\begin{document}

Une phrase en français; sans intérêt, avec signes diacritiques:
nous pouvons voir qu'il est correct!

\makebox[3cm][s]{Deux: point}

Les \og guillemets\fg{} sont corrects aussi.

Les «guillemets» sont corrects aussi.

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

[image]

The added example with the colon is exaggerated on purpose.

Comment: Is it possible to use `csquotes` for the quotes? Could you add it in affirmative case?

Comment: @Manuel Yes, it's possible. Desirable? I don't think so.

Comment: I mean to handle the french quotes (with spaces). Not desirable? In what sense?

Comment: @Manuel I prefer to see what I input. Quotes aren't generic markup, like `\emph` or an environment. The `csquotes` package was born mainly for managing citations.

Comment: I've never used `csquotes`, I was just asking to learn how it works, in case it's easy. So, okey.

Comment: @egreg, you're right. `babel` use thin space for `;!?`. I've made a mystake, I'm going to post an answer below (in the right box).

Comment: @egreg, you're right. `babel` use thin space for `;!?`. I've made a mystake. But (I don't know how to indent this answer) `babel` use normal space before `:` (and _I_  think it's too big) and use something like  normal space `\glue 2.66602 plus 0.49988 minus 0.88867` after/before `«»`  (which is _not_ imho the right thing to do). The `\showoutput` is great thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to use thin space with `«»` ? Is there a way to use thin space with `:` ?

Comment: @MatthieuThomas Didn't I show it?

Comment: Well, for `«»`, something like `\renewcommand{\og}{«\kern 0.16667em}
\renewcommand{\fg}{\kern 0.16667em»}`. I dont't know how to do this with `:` which is an active  character.

Comment: As a trick, I use `\defineshorthand{:}{\kern 0.16667em:}
\defineshorthand{!<}{«\kern 0.16667em}
\defineshorthand{!>}{\kern 0.16667em»}`, but I'm loosing the `AutoSpacePunctuation=true` for `:`. I must type `quelque chose: comme ça` and not `quelque chose : comme ça`.

Comment: @MatthieuThomas The rule exposed in the article you refer to is wrong: the spaces around the colon should be equal. In my example I show how you can directly use « and » and get the (horrible) French spacing.

Comment: @egreg In this article, as everywhere else, is it stated that the space after the colon should be a _normal space_ , and that the space **before** the colon should be _normal space but unbreakable and fixed_. Babel uses as a normal space and as space before the colon `\glue 3.33252 plus 1.66626 minus 1.11084`.  Babel uses as space for `«»` the value `\glue 2.66602 plus 0.49988 minus 0.88867`. In the two cases this is wrong : **these spaces must be fixed**. That's, in my opinion, why you find the French spacing horrible: is it way too large in `babel`.

Comment: @MatthieuThomas The spaces around the colon you see on the finely printed documents are always equal. They are different when programs just insert the “unbreakable space” before the colon, because it's a character that doesn't participate to space stretch or shrink (and different spaces are absurd). I'll add how to change the spaces inserted by `babel`, but not immediately.

Comment: OK, I will not fight windmills... I'm probably wrong if I'm the only one that  wants all these double-punctuation-spaces equal to `\kern 0.16667em`. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

from: [How to typeset a "small" non-breaking space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76132/how-to-typeset-a-small-non-breaking-space)

(1) the definition of `~` is

```
\leavevmode\nobreak\
```

(2) Change the `\nobreakspace` definition.

(3) I don't know about using babel to do it, but you can use `\,` to insert the thin unbreakable space.

EDIT: typo.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do what you require with the `babel-french` (frenchb) package: http://ctan.org/pkg/babel-french.

Answer (score 1):

I would like, in addition to the excellent response of egreg, add that `frenchb` from `babel` has [this option](ftp://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/required/babel/contrib/frenchb/frenchb.pdf) :

```
ThinColonSpace=true (false) changes the inter-word unbreakable space
added before the colon ‘:’ to a thin space, so that the same amount
of space is added before any of the four ‘high punctuation’ characters.
The default setting is supported by the French ‘Imprimerie Nationale’.
```