# Unbreakable space smaller than ~

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, line-breaking, cleveref

Using the [`cleveref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en) package for reference ranges, I'd like to change the standard `\crefrangeconjunction` from `_to~` to `_-_`, where the underscores represent spaces. Issuing

```
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{~-~}
```

I find the spaces are much too large. Defining instead

```
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{\,-\,}
```

is more compact and looks much better in my eyes but has the disadvantage of breaking at line ends.

Is there an unbreakable space smaller than `~`?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Thin unbreakable space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208964/2693).

Comment: btw: most typographical guidelines would use n-dashes, not hyphens, for this purpose and would not have spaces (let alone full spaces like ~) around the dash.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to typeset a “small” non-breaking space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76132/)

Comment: @Florian I'm aware of that. In fact, the [`cleveref` documentation](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) itself says "it is perfectly reasonable to define it [`\crefrangeconjunction`] to be an endash “--”". Call me crazy, but I really can't stand the look of it, though, so I'll stick with a hyphen for now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `-` that's causing the break, not `\,`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\unbreakablethinspace}{\leavevmode\,}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{
  a\unbreakablethinspace-\unbreakablethinspace b

  a\unbreakablethinspace\mbox{-}\unbreakablethinspace b
}

\end{document}
```

Hiding `-` in a box disallows the possibility of breaking at it.

I defined `\unbreakablethinspace` because `\,` might give surprises if used at the beginning of a paragraph. You can simply use `\,` if you're sure it will always go after a word.

[image]