# How to create list like this?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, description

> *A. some heading:* Text
>
> *B. another heading:* more Text
>
> *C. yet another head:* lots of Tex

I tried:

```
\begin{description}[\Alph]     %[font=$\Alph\ $\itshape]
    \item[some heading] Text
\end{description}
```

Comment: What is 'Head' here? This is unclear. Normally I would say an `enumerate` is much better than `description` here...It looks like you're using `enumitem` already...

Comment: yes, but I don't know, how to do both: description+numbering. Latex needs a one in all package :(

Comment: Like the fellow environment `itemize`, `description` is not numbered. It can be faked, but most times `enumerate` is easier, in my opinion -- but you were quickly choosing another answer before clearifying the question such that others had a chance to improve their post ;-)

Comment: Please enlighten me in this case with `enumerate`@ChristianHupfer

Comment: You're question was totally unclear, so in the aftermath of it there's no use in providing an `enumerate` - based answer, that's why I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the numbers in `Head1, Head2, ...` were supposed to be actual numbers or just example of headers, as in first header, second header, and so on.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{itemalph}
\setcounter{itemalph}{1}
\newcommand\xitem[1]{%
    \item[\Alph{itemalph}.~#1:]
    \stepcounter{itemalph}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[font=\normalfont\itshape]
    \xitem{Head1} description
    \xitem{Head2} description
    \xitem{Head3} description
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I modified the description of the problem, as it creating confusion. Thanks again

Comment: What is the meaning of `.~#1` in `\item[\Alph{itemalph}.~#1:]`

Comment: @Mr.EU Well,`\Alph{itemalph}.` creates `A.` and so on (the dot is there for that purpose),  `~` is a [non breakable and flexible space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76137/4778) and `#1` is the argument of `\xitem`. So `\xitem{Head1}` will produce `A. Head1:` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I define an `enumdescription` environment which does the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{enumdescr}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{enumdescription}{%
\setcounter{enumdescr}{0}%
\pretocmd{\descriptionlabel}{\refstepcounter{enumdescr}\enit@format\Alph{enumdescr}.~}{}{}
\apptocmd{\descriptionlabel}{:}{}{}
\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont\itshape}
\description}%
{\enddescription}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumdescription}
  \item[Head1] description
  \item[Head2] description
  \item[Head3] description
\end{enumdescription}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item[A. Head1:] Text
    \item[B. Head2:] Text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry.`laTex` is not WYSIWYG.

Comment: It was not immediately clear as to what you wanted at the time that I answered---I see you edited the question for clarity.