# A enumerate-like environment with description

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, description

How can I have a numbered list with a description for every item?
It should be something like:

1(desc1). balabala

2(desc2). balabala

3(desc3). balabala

I have read the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30029/enumerated-description-list), but it doesn't seem to be helpful (in my case).

Notice that the dot have to be after the description.

Comment: As  see, the answer of @Marco Daniel in linked question solve your problem. Or do I miss something? BTW, what you try so far?

Comment: @Zarko I tried his answer, but I can't solve the problem of the location of the dot.

Comment: @Zarko Besides that, the font of the numbers in the normal enumerate environment is decided by the "outer" environment, but Daniel's solution seem to fix the font.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328822/how-to-create-list-like-this/328848#328848) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution defining a new list environment `descenum` with `enumitem`. The `descenum` environment is basically the same as an enumerate environment, but in this environment (and only there) the `\item` command is modified to take an argument, which is placed between parentheses after the number of the enumerated item.

A short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{descenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[descenum]{%
    label={\arabic*},
    before={\changeitem},
    after={\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem}},
}
\newcommand{\changeitem}{%
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand{\item}[1]{\olditem (##1).\ }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{descenum}
    \item{First thing to be described} First description.
    \item{Second thing to be described} Second description.
\end{descenum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change how the described items are displayed, you can modify the `\changeitem` command, which renews the `\item` command. For example, if you want the described things to be in italic, you could replace

```
\newcommand{\changeitem}{%
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand{\item}[1]{\olditem (##1).\ }
}
```

with

```
\newcommand{\changeitem}{%
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand{\item}[1]{\olditem (\textit{##1}).\ }
}
```