# How to reduce the protected space a tilde (~) gets in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing

I really like to have a small space between a number (X) and a % sign, and never the percent sign on a new line. So usually I type `X~\%`. However, the distance generated this way is to large for me? Is there any way to consistently reduce it? Thank you!

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

 x~\%.  %too much horizontal space 

 x\%. % too few horizontal space

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does one of the commands in the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing/74354#74354) help?

Comment: If I'm understanding the question, one of the commands is probably the right amount of horizontal space, but would still allow the percent sign to jump to the next line.  Is there a way to specify that the horizontal space is not allowed to have a linebreak?

Comment: You might use `\,\%`. On the other hand, usually no space is added.

Comment: I believe the space inserted by, for example, `\,` is nonbreaking, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76132/how-to-typeset-a-small-non-breaking-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\,`, aka a non-breaking "thinspace", is your friend here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 x\%   & too little? \\
 x\,\% & about right? \\
 x~\%  & too much?
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still a bit big but someone posted a list so I will look it through. However, it is very interesting it has to have a space unlike (i.e., ~\% it is \, \%).